# __PHP_Incomplete_Class when trying to access an object stored in session

Tags: plugin, system-plugin

I work on implementing single sign on with joomla and simplesamlphp.

I try to use the simpleamlphp api in the context of a joomla plugin in the onAfterInitialise event.

To that end, the plugin in the onAfterInitialise event detects if there are in the parameters sent by the HTTP request one with name `simplesamlphp` and with value`sso`, if it is true I start the object `\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple` and start the authentication process by calling the `requireAuth()` method. This shows the simpleamlphp authentication form and by providing valid credentials redirects me to the site that initiated the authentication process, here I try to access the attributes of the authenticated user.

My problem is that I cannot access the attributes of the authenticated user in simplesamlphp because I cannot access the original instance of the `\SimpleSAML\ Auth\Simple` object

I am now trying to save the object in a session variable but I am getting the class error `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`

This is the code I'm trying

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');

class plgSystemMysamlredirect extends JPlugin
{
    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $application = JFactory::getApplication();
        $session = JFactory::getSession();

        $jinput = $application->input;

        $get = (object) $jinput->get->getArray();

        if (isset($get->simplesamlphp) && $get->simplesamlphp === 'sso') {
            $auth = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');

            $session->set('auth', $auth);

            $auth->requireAuth();
        }

        $auth = $session->get('auth');

        if (!is_null($auth)) {
            if ($auth->isAuthenticated()) {
                $attributes = $auth->getAttributes();

                print_r($attributes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update

to avoid the `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` error, before storing the object in session I do a cast a array and then to access it I do a cast object of the session variable. but when trying to call the `isAuthenticated()` method, the error returns with the message that the method does not exist

When setting

```
$session->set('authentication', (array) $authentication);
```

When getting

```
$authentication = (object) $session->get('authentication');
```

I welcome your comments and suggestions